# Angular animation creating too many elements

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-animations

I want to create component that, depends on its property (which changes on button click), shows one of the two divs (animating them while they 'enter' and 'leave'). 
Code and demo:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `

  <button (click)="show = !show">change</button><br><br>

  <div @trigger *ngIf="show" style="width: 200px; height:200px;  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);"></div>
  <div @trigger *ngIf="!show" style="width: 200px; height:200px;  background: red">

  </div>  
  `,
  animations: [
 trigger('trigger', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ width: '0' }),
        animate('3s ease-in', style({ width: '*' })),
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        animate('3s ease-in', style({ width: '0' }))
      ])
    ]),
  ]
})

export class AppComponent { 
  show: false;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2p2czs

Above i've posted sample code, however it works in a weird way. If animation is long enough and i click the button quickly couple times, it creates more than 2 divs, which is not what i want to achieve. Any ideas how to fix this? When the property changes while divs are still being animated i expect them to rollback animation from current state (don't know if its possible tho).

Comment: @DavidWalschots It's recommended to post the code, and then eventually add a demo project.

Comment: @DavidWalschots I did not say that he should no put the code in the question, please read again. I even said it was the recommended thing to do.

Comment: And I will add that as a user answering questions, those Stackblitz are quite useful. The reason why they are not forced is simply because they are external ressources and they could go down at any time.

Comment: What is this question title "Angular creating too many elements"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[code+demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdquqg?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

This happens because your animation insert/remove div it starts/ends.

There is a trick for this kind of animations, if you don't want Angular to create many divs, you can do this by using states on your animation, this way, no DOM is created/removed, only style modified.

```
<div [@trigger]="show ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"></div>
<div [@trigger]="!show ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"></div>
```

```
    trigger('trigger', [
      state('hidden', style({
        display: 'none',
      })),
      transition('hidden -> visible', [
        style({
          display: 'block',
          width: 0,
        }),
        animate('.5s ease', style({
          width: '*',
        }))
      ]),
      transition('visible -> hidden', [
        animate('.5s ease', style({
          width: 0,
        })),
      ])
    ]),
```